# Error con componente Transition (headdlesUI)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, transition, opacity

estoy utilizando el Transition de headdlesUI para hacer un loader, pero tengo un error con el segundo componente Child, tarda mucho en aparecer o dependiendo de la carga a veces ni aparece, e tratado de modificar los duration pero sin solucionarlo.

Lo que sale es un opacity:0 en el momento que no se ve, en el primer Child si funciona perfectamente.

utilizo la libreria headdlesUI para ello: https://headlessui.com/

Alguna idea?

Aca defino las Props para cambiar el state despues:

```
export default function MyModal({
  loading,
  lottie = 'defaultLoader',
  title,
  subtitle,
}: DialogProps) {
  const emptyRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentShown, setCurrentShown] = useState(loading);
  const [currentProps, setCurrentProps] = useState<Partial<DialogProps>>({
    lottie,
    title,
    subtitle,
  });

  const prevLoadingRef = useRef(loading);
  const prevCurrentShownRef = useRef(currentShown);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      prevLoadingRef.current === loading ||
      prevCurrentShownRef.current !== currentShown
    ) {
      setCurrentProps({
        lottie,
        title,
        subtitle,
      });
    }
    prevLoadingRef.current = loading;
    prevCurrentShownRef.current = currentShown;
  }, [currentShown, loading, lottie, title, subtitle]);
```

Aca dejo el return para la creacion del html, y la utilizacion del componente Transition, con sus dos Child:

```
 <Transition appear show={loading} as={Fragment}>
          <Dialog
            as="div"
            className="tw-relative tw-z-50"
            onClose={() => {}}
            initialFocus={emptyRef}
            aria-label="Loader"
          >
            <div
              className="tw-fixed tw-inset-0 tw-flex tw-min-h-full tw-overflow-y-auto tw-text-center lg:tw-p-4 [&>*]:tw-m-auto"
              aria-label="Loader wrapper"
            >
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="tw-duration-100 tw-ease-out"
              enterFrom="tw-opacity-0"
              enterTo="tw-opacity-100"
              leave="tw-duration-100 tw-ease-in"
              leaveFrom="tw-opacity-100"
              leaveTo="tw-opacity-0"
            >
              <div className="tw-fixed tw-inset-0 tw-bg-black tw-bg-opacity-50" />
            </Transition.Child>
    
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="tw-duration-100 tw-ease-out"
                enterFrom="tw-scale-95 tw-opacity-0"
                enterTo="tw-scale-100 tw-opacity-100"
                leave="tw-duration-100 tw-ease-in"
                leaveFrom="tw-scale-100 tw-opacity-100"
                leaveTo="tw-scale-95 tw-opacity-0"
                beforeEnter={() => {
                  setCurrentShown(true);
                }}
                afterLeave={() => {
                  setCurrentShown(false);
                }}
              >
                <Dialog.Panel
                  className={classNames(
                    'tw-relative tw-flex tw-aspect-square tw-max-w-[80%] tw-transform tw-flex-col tw-items-center tw-justify-center tw-overflow-auto tw-bg-white tw-text-center tw-align-middle tw-transition-all vw:tw-rounded-[9px] vw:tw-px-[40px] vw:tw-py-[51.2px] lg:tw-aspect-auto lg:tw-rounded-[6px] lg:rem:tw-max-w-[500px] lg:rem:tw-p-[20px]',
                    {
                      'tw-min-w-[50%] lg:tw-w-full lg:tw-min-w-0':
                        typeof currentProps.title === 'undefined' &&
                        typeof currentProps.title === 'undefined',
                      'tw-w-full':
                        typeof currentProps.title !== 'undefined' ||
                        typeof currentProps.subtitle !== 'undefined',
                    },
                  )}
                >
                  <div
                    className="tw-flex tw-flex-auto tw-items-center vw:tw-text-[154px] lg:rem:tw-text-[80px]"
                    ref={emptyRef}
                  >
                    <Lottie lottie={currentProps.lottie} />
                  </div>
                  {currentProps.title && (
                    <div className="tw-font-semibold vw:tw-text-[33px] lg:tw-text-[22px]">
                      {currentProps.title}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  {currentProps.subtitle && (
                    <div className="tw-font-light vw:tw-text-[24px] lg:tw-text-[16px]">
                      {currentProps.subtitle}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Dialog.Panel>
              </Transition.Child>
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        </Transition>
```